# Is the following subset of $R^3$ actually a linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

> All linear combinations of $v = (1,4,0)$ and $w = (2,2,2)$

To form a linear subspace the three properties must be satisfied:

1) $0$ is there
2) Closed by addition of vectors
3) Closed by multiplication of real-valued scalar.

I get $(c_1+2c_2;4c_1+2c_2;0+2c_2)$ so:

1) If $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$ the first property is done.

2) I have troubles to understand 2 and 3 properties. I read, that the set
 $(0,1)$={$x:x∈R,0<x<1$} is closed under multiplication, but not addition. $(0.6+0.7=1.3>10.6+0.7=1.3>1)$. But I still don't get it. HELP :(

Comment: All linear combinations of anything is a subspace

Comment: @ThePortakal Thanks. But the real problem for me is to understand what is the set of $v$ and $w$? What is the set of $v$ for example? I don't understand why they satisfy the 2nd and 3rd properties?

Comment: I feel like you're getting interval notation and vector definition confused. They both use curvey braces but are not the same. This question actually has nothing to do with intervals, so just ditch that. The subspace you are considering is $\{x | a  v + b  w, a \text{ and } b\text{ are scalars}\}$. As is already stated, this is a subspace.

Comment: Actually by that exact definition you can see why the 2nd and 3rd property are satisfied.

Comment: @whyyes I feel ashamed. I can't see it... though I know the definition

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan Don't despair. Everyone find their own things hard.

Comment: Yeah @SargisIskandaryan this is much less about math acumen and more about applying definitions, which is definitely something we all struggle with. The key is to see that "closed under addition" means $x\in S, y\in S \iff x+y\in S$ and "closed under scalar multiplication means $x\in S \iff ax\in S$ for all scalar $a$. The subspace in your problem is defined explicitly as $S = \{x | av + bw\}$ for any scalar $a$ and $b$. If you agree with my three statements so far, the rest is to just do the proof yourself that the two conditions are satisfied for this choice of $S$.

Comment: @whyyes Your arrows should probably only be one way; consider $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ in the usual manner. Then, $(0, 0, 1) + (0, 0, -1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $0\cdot (0, 0, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but obviously $(0, 0, 1) \notin \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Yeah so what I mean is actually $x\in S \iff (ax \in S \;\forall a \text{ scalar})$ which is why the $a=0$ example isn't sufficient, but yes good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work through it, step by step.

First, let $V = \{a_1(1, 4, 0) + a_2(2, 2, 2) : a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$, that is, $V$ is the set of all linear combinations of $(1, 4, 0)$ and $(2, 2, 2)$. So, we must show that $0 \in V$. This is done by noting that $0 = 0\cdot (1, 4, 0) + 0\cdot (2, 2, 2)$.

Next, let $a_1(1, 4, 0) + a_2(2, 2, 2) \in V$ and $a_3(1, 4, 0) + a_4(2, 2, 2) \in V$. Then, $(a_1(1, 4, 0) + a_2(2, 2, 2)) + (a_3(1, 4, 0) + a_4(2, 2, 2)) = (a_1 + a_3)(1, 4, 0) + (a_2 + a_4)(2, 2, 2)) \in V$, so $V$ is closed under vector addition.

Finally, let $a_1(1, 4, 0) + a_2(2, 2, 2) \in V$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $c(a_1(1, 4, 0) + a_2(2, 2, 2)) = (ca_1)(1, 4, 0) + (ca_2)(2, 2, 2) \in V$, so $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication, and moreover, $V$ is a subspace.

The important thing to note in this proof is that not once did I refer to any properties of $(1, 4, 0)$ or $(2, 2, 2)$. This is because, given any set of vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ in any vector space, the set of all their linear combinations is *automatically* a subspace, as the other answers and comments point out.

Comment: Your answer shed a light to some of my thoughts. I understood it, but doubth if I can implement the same logic to other subsets. I feel I must read this part in Russian. However, thank you!

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan Here are two challenges to you, to help you understand it: 1) Show that the set of all linear combinations of $(2, 1, 3)$ and  $(1, 1, 9)$ is a subspace. 2) Let $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ be a set of vectors. Show that the set of all linear combinations of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a subspace. The first is essentially the same as this question, but you should try it yourself to help you understand it. The second is a (very important), more general version of this question, which should help you see what's *really* going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a subspace. The span of any set of vectors is always a subspace, since a linear combination of linear combinations is a linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

Note, this answer essentially does the same as Duncan Ramage's, however I have written it out without referencing the specific vectors so that you can see the general principle.

---

The set of all linear combinations of $v$ and $w$, denoted as $\operatorname{Span}(v,w)$ is the set of all vectors of the form

$$
av + bw
$$

with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, take two vectors of this form and denote them as $a_1v + b_1w$ and $a_2v + b_2w$. Then we have

$$
(a_1v + b_1w) + (a_2v + b_2w) = (a_1 + a_2)v + (b_1 + b_2)w
$$

so the sum is also in $\operatorname{Span}(v,w)$. Moreover, if $k \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$$
k(a_1v + b_1w) = (ka_1)v + (kb_1)w
$$

so a scalar multiple is also in $\operatorname{Span}(v,w)$.